# How do I change text (and others) in the popup in ngx-guided-tour?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am using https://github.com/lsqlabs/ngx-guided-tour to guide users through the product that was made using Angular 8.

Under this readme: https://github.com/lsqlabs/ngx-guided-tour#ngx-guided-tour-component-inputs it is mentioned that the change of text for all the buttons is possible, but unfortunately, there is no example snippet present. Can someone please help me on this?

Please have a look at the image below for my requirement.

[image]

To sum it up, how do it set that skipText and where do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ngx-guided-tour skipText="new skip text"></ngx-guided-tour>` where you you put `<ngx-guided-tour></ngx-guided-tour>` works fine.

If you look at those docs there are a couple of other text properties if you need them too.

Answer (score 2):

The file `guided-tour.component.ts` has the html and typescript code for the above popup. The variable skipText is on line 104

```js
@Input() public skipText ?= 'Skip';
```

Which means that `skipText` is an input variable, but if we don't provide any value for the input, then the default value will be 'Skip'.

You can change the default value from 'Skip' to 'Close', if you want change the text for all steps.
But if you want to change it for any specific step, then you could deisplay a different text based on `GuidedTourService.onLastStep` condition, or change the value of `skipText` itself inside the `nextStep()` method, there are so many ways to achieve this.